# Signet::AuthorizationError error while using google-drive gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using `google_drive` gem.

This is `config.json`.

```
{
  "client_id": "*****.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "client_secret": "*****",
  "scope": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"
  ],
  "refresh_token": "*****"
}
```

Code: Add row to google sheet.

```
session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_config("#{Rails.root.join('config/config.json')}")
ws = session.spreadsheet_by_key(ENV["GOOGLE_SHEET_KEY"]).worksheets[0]
num_rows = ws.num_rows

worksheet_row.each_with_index do |column, index|
  ws[num_rows + 1, index + 1] = column
end
```

It was working but recently I am getting this error.

```
Signet::AuthorizationError (Authorization failed.  Server message:
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}):
```

Any idea?

Comment: I would guess your refresh token is no longer valid.